# How to Forms of 2 models in one form?

Tags: yii

I have two tables `assignments` and `assignments Marks`. I need to insert data to `assignments Marks` table when `assignment` table fill with data, I do it according to  [How to use a single form to collect data for two or more models?](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/19/how-to-use-a-single-form-to-collect-data-for-two-or-more-models). But I got this error:

[image]

Comment: if you don't share the code, nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: It is better to include code and error message as text.